# True title casing in various languages in .NET

Tags: .net, localization, cultureinfo, title-case

I need to convert a bunch of text in different languages to their title case versions. According to the official MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netcore-3.1), `ToTitleCase` is not always linguistically correct because it usually always converts the first character to uppercase. See [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

Is there a 3rd-party library I could use to properly convert words to title case in various languages?

Comment: Have a look at https://humanizr.net/.

Comment: I set the current culture to German using Humanizr and tested `Per Anhalter durch die Galaxis`. It did not work.